# How did Vrishbhanu (father of Radha) life end? What happened to him?

Tags: krishna, radha

How did Vrishbhanu (father of Radha) life end? What happened to him? 
At which point of situation Vrishbhanu life ended?  What happened to Radha after that?

Answer (score 3):

After Dantavakra gets killed, Krishna returns to Vrindavana and stays there for 2 months. After that,all ascend to highest Vaikuntha(Goloka Vrindavan). There is no description of their death. All residents of Vrindavan along with Vrishabanu and Radha ascended to the spiritual world.

> Hearing that Śiśupāla was dead, Dantavakra came to Mathurā to fight
>   Kṛṣṇa. Hearing this, Kṛṣṇa got on his chariot and went to Mathurā to
>   fight him. The two fought day and night at the gate of Mathurā on the
>   bank of the Yamunā. Kṛṣṇa killed him with his club. Dantavakra, like a
>   mountain hit by a thunderbolt, with all his limbs smashed, gave up his
>   life and fell to the ground. He attained sāyujya, the supreme, eternal
>   destination filled with eternal bliss, attained by yogīs. Thus Jaya
>   and Vijaya, on the pretext of the Kumāras curse, appeared in the world
>   only for the pastimes of the Lord and in three births were killed by
>   the Lord. At the end of the third birth they were liberated.
>
> After killing him, Kṛṣṇa, crossing the Yamunā, went to Vraja and
>   greeting his original parents, comforted them, and was embraced by
>   them with tears in their throats. He offered respects to all the elder
>   cowherds and satisfied everyone present with jewel ornaments.
>
> On the bank of the Yamunā, covered with pure trees, Kṛṣṇa played
>   constantly with the gopīs. Wearing the dress of a cowherd he lived
>   there for two months with full rasa of prema, Padma Purāṇa 6.252.19-27
>
> **All persons present in Vraja headed by Nanda, along with their wives
>   and sons, cows, animals and birds, attained spiritual forms by the
>   mercy of Vāsudeva. They mounted an airplane and went to the supreme
>   Vaikuṇṭha planet.** Kṛṣṇa, having given his supreme, pure abode to the
>   people of Gokula, entered Dvārakā, while being praised by devatās in
>   the sky. Padma Purāṇa 6.252.28-29

One may think that according to Bhagavatam, after the end of Kurukshetra war, residents of Vrindavan and Krishna met, but it is not true, 10th Canto of Bhagavatam doesn't describe all events in chronological order.

Their meeting happened before Kurukshetra war in fact long before the war. One evidence is that even Bhisma and Drona came to that meeting during solar eclipse and hence, that event happened before the war in which both Bhisma and Drona died.

SB 10.82.23:
**bhīṣmo droṇo** ’mbikā-putro
gāndhārī sa-sutā tathā
sa-dārāḥ pāṇḍavāḥ kuntī
sañjayo viduraḥ kṛpaḥ

The chronology of the events is given by Sanatana Goswami in Brihad Vaishnava Toshani commentary to the 10th Canto.

Or one may refer Gopala Champu of Jiva Goswami which is a poetry work where in he described events from the time Krishna is born till the time all the Vrindavan residents go back to Goloka Vrindavan in the chronological order.